# how to make a light-weighted stanford-nlp.jar

Tags: stanford-nlp

I've noticed the whole library is quite large, ~300MB. But I'm only using tokenize, ssplit, pos. How can I make a light library? Many thanks.

Best,
Huang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want part of speech tags, you can include just the part of speech tagger models; for example, as downloaded from: nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml. You can also safely just go ahead and remove unwanted models from the models jar to make it smaller.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use winzip to unzip and remove unecessary files and zip. It didn't work. I then tried to create a project in eclipse, and removed files from eclipse and exported to a jar. It worked!